# Deploy using IIS Web Deploy (WMSv)c with basic auth fails but NTLM works?

Tags: windows, visual-studio-2010, iis-7, webdeploy

I'm trying to setup Web Deploy on IIS 7, so that 1-click publishing in Visual Studio works.

Every time i try and publish the app i get a 401 error, which seems to be failing to auth against WMSvc.  I have set the build output verbosity to detailed and can see the web deploy command being used.  When i try and run it from the command prompt i get the same 401 error (ERROR_USER_UNAUTHORIZED), however when i change the the authType parameter in the command from basic to NTLM it works fine and publishes correctly...

As far as i was aware WMSvc only worked with basic auth and not NTLM.  As far as my server config goes i have tried setting the management service to accept only windows users and to allow Windows users and management service users, neither setting seems to make any odds.

I can connect fine using IIS manager locally to the remote server, but as soon as i try and use any of the export functionality on the remote server i get permission issues from the remote connection.  This all seems most odd, can any one shed some light on this behaviour?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just providing the answer that worked for me, after searching in vain I stumbled upon [an article](http://haacked.com/archive/2007/05/21/the-iis-7-team-rocks.aspx) by Phil Haack (whilst looking for something else entirely):

It turned out I had a URL-ACL defined which was stopping everything from working.
Followed the instructions in that post and it all just worked like it should :-)

I personally wish web deploy was a bit less fragile when it comes to setting it up, works great once you've gone through the pain.